# joomla custom component translation compatibility

Tags: components, translate, joomla3.1

What would be the best workaround to make a joomla3.1 custom component multi language platform compatible? What I mean I have the site running on 3 languages, my component should  be able to show translated items of my component

```
realestates

  --realestate(items) - en-EN
  --realestate(items) - de-DE
  --realestate(items) - cn-CN
```

Would be a good workaround to extend my items table with a column `translation` which keeps the translation language code an each time the query would take this in consideration

```
select * item from realestets where translation = 'en-EN'
```

or there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your component to be multilingual you need to define languages files which are stored in the `language` folder in both the administrator and public side of the website. These language files are `.ini` files which should be defined for every language you want to include. So if you do english and dutch your files `.ini` files should be in:

`/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_yourcom.ini`

`/language/nl-NL/nl-NL.com_yourcom.ini`

Then every string should be passed to the translator method `_()` (yes that's an underscore) in the `JText` class like so:

`JText::_("COM_YOURCOM_STRING")` where `COM_YOURCOM_STRING` is simply a string in your component.

I recommend using short string descriptions if the string you are translating is a large block of text.

EDIT:
For your specific case I would add a column `translation_id` to your table where the items are stored. Then create a new table with 3 (or 4) columns where the translations are stored:

`id, item_id, (language), translation`

In your component xml you could add an entry which generates a dropdown to define what language your item is in. If it's anything other than the default language, it should create a new entry in the translations table.

I would also suggest to take a look how Joomla! manages languages internally and also how Joomfish works!

Good resources:

http://docs.joomla.org/Embedding_translatable_strings_in_the_template

http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files

http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Guidelines_for_3rd_Party_Extensions

Comment: and what about records which are created dynamically how do you translate theme? Whit ini files I have no problems that's works

Comment: You should not generate languages dynamically. If for instance you generate something like: I have $x apples, you need to use `JText::sprintf()`. Google: jtext sprintf. You will then pass the variable as an argument to a language string. Inside the language string definition you can use `%d` for digits and `%s` for strings.

Comment: Maybe is not clear what I want. I want to be able to translate the content of my component in different languages. The content is handled by mysql.

Comment: @fefe That's the fundamental problem with your component. You should not store translatable strings in your database. Why do you even store it in your db?

Comment: okay let me more specific: I have a real estate(en) attributes are saved in db(like price, description!!!). How you are going to translate description on real estate in german, if description needs to be updated in different circumstances?

Comment: Now I understand. Updated my answer